Accessing Zepp Life data in Watchface API
I'm trying to develop a custom watchface for Mi Band 7 using ZeppOS Watchface API.
My intent is to present data from Zepp Life mobile app, to which the band is connected.
Is there any way to access such data using Watchface API?
I noticed some pre-built watchfaces presenting stress data from app, but in the API the stress sensor seems to actually show systolic blood pressure (which is a constant value, as the band does not support pressure measurement).
I also didn't find a way to access EPOC data, or weight/physique assesment data (the latter might be difficult, as I assume it's collected by a different device - body composition scale).
